# What type of SD card do I need to use as Windows Ready Boost memory?

Tags: windows, memory, sd-card, readyboost

I have a laptop with an SD card reader and was wanting to buy and SD card to use as ready boost memory.

Is there a specific type of SD card that is required so that windows can access it?

Answer (score 4):

There is [speed requirement](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomarcher/archive/2006/06/02/615199.aspx) but any newer SD card should be fast enough.

However, I would go for fastest one that you can find in order to maximize effect.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the type of card reader has an impact - if your card reader's slots appear as drives all the time i.e. with or without card inserted, then you can't use the card reader for ReadyBoost.

If the Windows drive only appears when a card is inserted then you can use the reader for ReadyBoost.

Answer (score 2):

as a reminder: while ReadyBoost might be acceptable if your strapped for system resources somewhere in the wilderness, it is by no means a substitute for physical memory which happens to be dirt cheap these days. :)